# How to open my app with deep linking instead of redirecting to google play store site?

Tags: android, deep-linking, intentfilter

I've tried to open my app directly, without opening google play store or browser, when user tap on the link.

I've tried this code:

```
     <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="fptest"
                android:host="forgot"
                android:pathPrefix="/"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

I'm using link as follows

<a href="intent://TestApplication#Intent;scheme=fptest;package=com.example.testapplication;end">  
   Open App
 </a>

where , 
   TestApplication -- my app name
   package -- com.example.testapplication
```

But it always open Google Play or a Browser , not my app.

I want to open my app from a link eg : fptest://forgot . I dont want to use http as scheme

Answer (score 1):

Add this as your link

```
<a href="intent://forgot#Intent;scheme=fptest;package=com.example.testapplication;end">  
   Open App
 </a>
```

Note: I replaced TestApplication with forgot you need to use host after the `intent://`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by the below code. You don't need to change anything if you are opening your own app. However, if you are willing to open a different app, then just change `getPackageName` with that specific one.

```
@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    public void OpentheApp()
    {
        Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName()));
        localIntent.addFlags(1208483840);
        try
        {
            startActivity(localIntent);
        }
        catch (Exception localException)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName())));
        }
    }
```

If you want to open it by `webview`. Then Follow this:
Declare these two on the Activity.

```
String market_url = "market://details?id=package_name";
String website_url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=package_name";
```

Inside OnCreate:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");               // path to html
webview.setWebViewClient(new Callback());


    private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.equals(website_url)) {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(market_url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                }
            }
            return (false);
        }
    }
```

index.html

```
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=package_name">App link</a>
```

It will open the app in the play store.

Comment: Hi thank you for your time. I want to open my own application which is installed in my device. Actually , my function is to send a link to mail for resetting password . On click of link, our application should get open (if it is installed). I dont want to open play store. If i'm giving scheme http , then app will open . But i dont want to add http , my url is for eg: fptest://forgot

Answer (score 0):

```
<data
       android:host="www.yourdomain.com"
       android:pathPrefix="/api/forgot"
       android:scheme="https"
</data>
```

Then handle the data in `onCreate()` and `onNewIntent()`.
Your host should be the complete domain of the incoming url.
PathPrefix should be the path segments
And scheme should could any of http/https/etc

You can use a URL like:-
https://www.yourdomain.com/api/forgot/abc.php

Comment: Hi thank you for your time . I want to use custom scheme (not https/http) .